# Phonegap app on Microsoft Surface Pro -- offline storage options

Tags: angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins, indexeddb

We want to develop a hybrid app using Angular.js, Twitter Bootstrap, .Net Rest API, indexedDB, and phonegap and deploy it to iPads and Surface Pros.

We know phonegap based apps using indexeddb as the offline storage method will not work on Surface Pro as IE10/IE11 doesnt support indexeddb. Phonegap SQL Lite Plugin also doesnt support Surface Pro.

What offline storage methods are supported by both Surface Pro and iPad?

Comment: what are your storage requirements... how much data are you trying to store locally on the devices?

Comment: We are trying to store more than 50 MB of data. Currently We have decided to use Phonegap SQL Lite plugin for iOS, but not sure what is the best approach for surface pro.

Comment: @JRulle - do you know any good offline storage that Windows 8 supports?

Comment: I have not had a need to store data of that volume (50MB). HTML5 Local Storage has been more than enough for my use cases so far so I haven't looked into it further. Also, I am not sure about your statement that indexeddb will not work in IE10/11 - support is partial but it may warrant further investigation.

Comment: @JRulle - You are correct. The solution we are building may work in IE 10/11, unless we test the solution , we cannot say it doesnt work in Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to look at IndexedDB. It has maximum size limits but there is always a way to get more space.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772651%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/

Comment: I was looking into SQLLite Database to see if it would work with ipad and surface pro. Is the SQLLite database ( http://www.sqlite.org/about.html ) different from phonegap sqllite plugin ( https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin)? From SQLLite documentation it seems they support windows 8.1 , whereas phonegap sqllite plugin doesnt seem to support windows 8.1. Do I need  separate solution for iPAD and surface pro?